# Is there any type trait which controls member type(not member variable)

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

STL comes with many type traits like `std::is_pointer`, `std::is_reference` etc...

Lets say I have a class

```
class A 
{
   using type_member = void;     
}
```

Is there any type trait for controlling the type member and checking if it exists ?
Something like `is_type_member_exist<typename A::type_member>();`

I am both curious if a solution exist with C++17 and also curious about C++2003(at work I need this and I have vs2010 which has a bit C++11 support but not complete).

Comment: Member variables and member types are different things I believe. Member types may differ since they are pure types. Language may come up with a easier solution for them. The question you directed does not helps me .

Comment: Look up `void_t`.

Comment: Look at [`is_detected`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1169/sfinae-substitution-failure-is-not-an-error/18585/is-detected).

Comment: Guys is it possible for you to write a answer with an example

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain why the answer's with examples in @MooingDuck's link don't answer your question (and edit to show the difference)?

Comment: @OJFord - sorry but... are you able to use the answer's in examples in MooingDuck's link to write an answer to this question? I'm not.

Comment: @max66 Your answer's good, and I think I understand now, I just thought the question could do with better explaining the difference of this problem.

Comment: @OJFord - the question isn't clear and should be written better; I'm agree with you. But I think that close it because it's a duplicate of a really different question is bad.

Comment: I liked @max66 answer i am not looking for a solution but instead best alternative that is why before accepting his answer I wanted to see example with is-detected . And now sadly question marked as a duplicate

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir - yes, I'm interested in answer is_detected based too. I'm marked to reopen but you can open another question stressing that is different than asking a way to detect if, in a class/struct, it's a member (variable) or not.

Comment: @max66 I am just afraid it will be tagged duplicated again. The only problem I don't know how to ask more clearly unfortunately I stressed that it is not a member variable but member type even in the question title. I put an example with member type. I think I won't be able to learn if there is a good method for member types from stackoverflow if there is any

Comment: @max66: Example of code with `is_detected`: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e3dd1d75e816413) (the first 40 lines should be unneeded with C++17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `type_member` is `public` (and not `private` as in your question), I suppose you can do something like

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
struct with_type_member
 { 
   template <typename Y = X>
   static constexpr bool getValue (int, typename Y::type_member * = nullptr)
    { return true; }

   static constexpr bool getValue (long)
    { return false; }

   static constexpr bool value { getValue(0) };
 };

class A 
 {
   public:
      using type_member = void;     
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << with_type_member<int>::value << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << with_type_member<A>::value << std::endl;   // print 1
 }
```

Hope this helps.